# Estimation of the Data logging size

Tags: c, hard-drive, plc, st

I have a device generating some values say N, each value having 32 bit.
I am logging these values every 10 seconds by writing a new row in an excel file. I will be creating a new file every day.
I have to estimate the hard disk storage capacity necessary to store these log files for a period of 10 years.
Can someone give any hints regarding the calculation of the size of log file generated per day ?

Comment: Excel can, and any other calculator can as well. But first you need to explain (to yourself at least) what exactly are you writing, in which format, and for what duration.

Comment: As I am using structured text, values are of type DWORD (32 bit)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming worst case 2's complement 32-bit ASCII...
-2147483648 is 13 characters per value

- 1 value / 10 seconds

3600 seconds / hour

24 hours /day

that's 112,320 bytes per day, per number of values N,

"round" that off to **112,640 bytes** (divisible by 1024) **per day**

365.25 days per year

10 years

that's **N * 411,417,600** or slightly more than **N * 4Mbytes**

So if **N was 10**, that would be slightly more than **41MBytes.**

Comment: thank you for the ideas, it is a smart one.

Comment: Just a correction: 13 characters x N columns x 6 times per second x 60 min X 24 hours = n bytes per day

Comment: @soulemanemoumie corrected

Comment: Please just a rectification in my previous comment:

Comment: 13 characters x N columns x 6 times per minutes x 60 min X 24 hours = n bytes per day

Comment: as every 10 seconds is equivalent to 6 times per minute

Comment: I think you're off by a factor of 10 or so. There are 86400 seconds per day, so roughly 10k measurements per day. There are roughly 4k days in 10 years. And there are roughly 10 bytes per record (partly compensates for over-estimates on the other two numbers). 10k x 4k * 10 = 400M rather than just 40M. The third and fourth digits in the estimate are spurious; so probably is any second digit. One of the comments says '4 bytes per record'; that may be correct for the value, but there's probably coordinate information too. Measurements, as suggested by the other answer, would help calibrate this.

Answer (score 0):

Create a sample spreadsheet. Add 1000 rows and save it as a different name.

That will give an estimate for per-row cost.

Incremental writing is not a good scenario for complex formats such as spread sheet.  Text log file could be appended.

A spread sheet would tend to re-write whole file for each flush.